Trouble Fetching Posts Using WordPress API: No Response from Specific Category
I'm facing difficulties while retrieving posts via the WordPress API, specifically when attempting to fetch posts from a particular category. Here's the issue in detail:
Fetching Posts by Category:
When using the endpoint https://mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=271, I consistently receive an empty array as a response. However, I'm certain that the category with ID 271 exists and contains posts. What could be causing this lack of response from this specific category?
Additionally, when trying to fetch a specific post using its slug via the endpoint https://mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=test-post, I notice a peculiar behavior. If the post is categorized as 'trending' (the ID of this category is 271), the API call returns an empty response. However, changing the post's category to a different one allows the API call to retrieve the post successfully.
Could there be any specific reasons or configurations within the WordPress setup that might be causing this issue with fetching posts from this particular category?
Any insights or troubleshooting suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Is the 'category' the default WP Category taxonomy?
